# Opacity problems with simple tab image gallery (CSS + jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've put together a very basic tab image gallery and am now in the process of styling it, but am having some trouble getting the 'default' thumbnail to load with max opacity. My `jQuery` is also messing with my `hover css`. I did try using the `focus`/`active` css to set opacity to 1 on click rather than jQuery, but it didn't seem to work.

**Desired effect**

The page loads and image 1 is shown in the main image frame. The thumbnail for image 1 has full opacity while the other 3 have `opacity:0.8`. When hovering over an unselected thumbnail, `opacity:1`. After clicking a thumbnail, the picture in the main frame changes and the opacity of the newly clicked thumbnail is set to 1 (whilst the opacity for image 1 returns to 80%).

**Issues**

The 'default' thumbnail loads at 80% opacity rather than 1.

If I add the latter 2 lines to my jQuery (shown below) to set opacity on click, the 'hover' effect stops working after something has been clicked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(".thumbnail").css("opacity", "0.8");
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });
})
```

```css
#thumbnails img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#thumbnails img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='gallery'>
  <div id='panel'>
    <img id='mainimage' src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/large-breed-dogs-1581096488.jpg' width=80%  />
  </div>

  <div id='thumbnails'>
    <center> <img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/large-breed-dogs-1581096488.jpg' class='thumbnail' style='opacity: 1;'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-puppy-lying-down-on-grass-royalty-free-image-1587052215.jpg' class='thumbnail'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gettyimages-589656325-1-1586896598.jpg' class='thumbnail'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/chihuahua-dog-running-across-grass-royalty-free-image-1580743445.jpg' class='thumbnail'></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: By setting the opacity of the default image to 1 using `<... style=opacity:1;>` I'm able to get it to have default opacity on page load. I fiddled around with another `jQuery` that changed opacity on hover, but this had the negative affect of setting the opacity of the thumbnail that was last hovered over to 1 rather than the one that was last clicked. At this point, the main issue us that my `hover css` is not working with the `jQuery`posted above.

Comment: Can you stick in some real images (from anywhere online - flickr etc) so that when we run the snippet we can see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Have added some pictures of cute dogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `jQuery` to set a `CSS` attribute you are adding it `inline`. `Inline styles` override `CSS` styles. The only way to get around this is to stick an `!important` after the style that you want to override the inline. In your case, its on the hover.

Hierarchy of CSS works like this, in order of importance and priority being rendered. Ie, if 1 isn't there, render 2 and so on:

> 1. CSS Style with !Important
> 2. Inline style
> 3. ID
> 4. Specific Class
> 5. Less specific class

See working snippet below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $("#mainimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(".thumbnail").css("opacity", "0.8");
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  });
})
```

```css
#thumbnails img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#thumbnails img:hover {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='gallery'>
  <div id='panel'>
    <img id='mainimage' src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/large-breed-dogs-1581096488.jpg' width=80%  />
  </div>

  <div id='thumbnails'>
    <center> <img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/large-breed-dogs-1581096488.jpg' class='thumbnail' style='opacity: 1;'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-puppy-lying-down-on-grass-royalty-free-image-1587052215.jpg' class='thumbnail'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gettyimages-589656325-1-1586896598.jpg' class='thumbnail'><img src='https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/chihuahua-dog-running-across-grass-royalty-free-image-1580743445.jpg' class='thumbnail'></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for! Really appreciate your help.